# Galaxy S10e stuck on boot screen - cannot get into download mode or recovery

Tags: custom-roms, boot, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I have Galaxy S10e (beyond0lte), which had crDroid 11 installed. I flashed the latest stock firmware, then TWRP 3.7.0.0 patched with Magisk 25.0 using Odin and was able to get into TWRP. In TWRP I installed the crDroid 12 zip. It appeared to succeed, I wiped cache/Dalvik cache as suggested, and rebooted. My phone is now stuck on the boot screen showing

> This phone is not running Samsung's official software. (blah blah blah)
>
> Samsung Galaxy S10e

I left it like that for a good half hour just in case.

The only thing I can do now is reboot by holding Vol Down + Power. **I cannot get into recovery mode nor download mode**, no matter how many times I try the key combinations (Vol Up/Down + Bixby + Power) - it just goes back to that screen. I was able to do both before installing the crDroid 12 ZIP. Is there anything I can do to recover this phone?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the stock firmware update changed what needs to be done to get into recovery or download mode!

I now need to have the USB cable connected to a computer while pressing the same key combo (Volume Up + Bixby + Power). Some say to have it connected to power only, not a computer, but that didn't work for me. To get into download mode I now have to power off the phone and hold down Volume Down + Bixby while plugging in the USB cable.